# How to create an assertion that can display multiple values as result?

Tags: json

I have a JSON response as such:

```
{
"customer": [ {
"contactdetails": [      {
     "address": "10 Broadway",
     "city": "New York",
     "state": "New York",
     "country": "USA"
     } ]
  }]
}
```

I want to add an assertion using JSON Match that will give the result as **10 Broadway, New York, USA**. Could someone help me in this?

Comment: customer[0]['contactdetails'][0]['address']

Comment: The above code would give only 10 Broadway as the result. I need the result as 10 Broadway, New York, USA

Comment: i just showed one example.

Comment: customer[0]['contactdetails'][0]['address'].','.customer[0]['contactdetails'][0]['city'].','.customer[0]['contactdetails'][0]['country'];

Comment: I tried with commas like customer[0]['contactdetails'][0]['address'],customer[0]['contactdetails'][0]['city'],customer[0]['contactdetails'][0]['country'] but its an invalid JSON expression.

Comment: in which language you are doing above?

Comment: Your solution didnt work. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101347/discussion-between-rohan-khude-and-irine-mathew).